# JavaScript - check if object's property is an array

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
const foo = {
   prop1: 'I am a string',
   prop2: [
           { prop2_1: 'I am a sub string' },
           { prop2_2: 'I am a sub string' },
   ],
   prop3: 'I am a string',
   prop4: [
           { prop4_1: 'I am a sub string' },
           { prop4_2: 'I am a sub string' },
   ],
}
```

In JavaScript (ie not jQuery), how can I loop thru foo's properties and determine if any of it's properties are arrays? I tried this with no luck:

```
for (const prop in foo) {
  if (prop!== undefined) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(prop) === '[object Array]') {
      prop.map((child) => {
          // do something
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean recursively? i.e. are there ever sub-properties?

Comment: yes, sorry for the omission

Comment: `prop` is always a string, I think you meant `foo[prop]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two errors

firstly, const prop will fail, because a const is constant

secondly, prop is the key, so it will never be an array

the corrected code is

```
for (let prop in foo) {
  if (foo.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(foo[prop]) === '[object Array]') {
      foo[prop].map((child) => {
          // do something
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the better answer!

Comment: it works now, but with using EcmaScript6 and EsLint, const was the correct pointer

Comment: `const was the correct pointer` ?? I don't understand what you mean - using const would mean in node prop is always `prop1`, or an error in firefox (yes, firefox does understand const, just doesn't like you trying to assign a value to it more than once)

Comment: babel converts it to var in the end

Comment: `for (const prop in obj)` actually works because in each iteration there is a new `prop` "variable". It's not reassigned.

Comment: @FelixKling - using const prop that way results in an error output in firefox - and props value is prop1 in each iteration of the loop in node and in chrome - my point was based on observed behaviour, not  speculative interpretation of a spec :p

Comment: There is nothing speculative about this, the spec is pretty clear in this point. If browsers don't implement this correctly, then it's valuable to point this out, but saying that it is incorrect is ... incorrect.

Comment: @FelixKling - you said it `actually works` - I've tried it in three environments, all failed. I even tried looking at the ES2015 spec to see if a const in the `for(...)` part of a loop is scoped the same as a const in the body of the `for` loop - I have not found the right part of the spec

Comment: @FelixKling - I owe you sort of an apology ... "use strict" fixes chrome and node - firefox remains broken

Comment: Fwiw, http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofbodyevaluation-lhs-stmt-iterator-lhskind-labelset is where to look at. It describes that a new environment is created in each iteration, and new bindings are created in that environment. Firefox still uses an old/non-standard `const` implementation afaik.

Answer (score 3):

You want `Array.isArray`.

You may need to polyfill this.

**Non-recursive**

```
Object.keys(foo).some((k) => Array.isArray(foo[k]));
```

**Recursive**

```
function containsArr(o) {
    for (var k of Object.keys(o)) {
        if (recursive(o[k])) {
            if (containsArr(o[k])) {
                return true;
            }
            continue;
        }

        if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// We recurse into functions 
// and plain objects.
function recursive(o) {
    return /^\[object (Object)| (Function)\]/
      .test(Object.prototype.toString.call(o));
}
```

Comment: Care to share an example of doing ti recursively? ;)

Comment: In this case, wouldn't `c` be a key and not a value meaning it's always a string?

Comment: The first statement should be more efficient using [*some*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.some) or [*every*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.every) so that it exits as soon as the result is known, e.g. `Object.keys(foo).some(x => Array.isArray(foo[x]))`, which is also less to type. ;-)

Comment: StackOverflow, being clickish, has many who want to show off and few who want to help.